# How to update new column based on exsisting column in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a dataframe 'df' with column df['dead_notdead'] which has values as [{'out'}, {'out','soak'}.....] I want to create a column named df['Fatal'] and if value of df['dead_notdead'] is empty then df['Fatal'] should be 0 else 1.

file format
df size 16343

```
Input
    index      Dead_notdead
    0           {'out'}
    1            {}
    2            {'out','shock,'kill'}  

Output
   index    Dead_notdead             Fatal
    0       {'out'}                   1
    1        {}                       0 
    2       {'out','shock','kill'}    1
```

Tried code:

```
k=df['Dead_notdead']
s=[]

for (i in range(len(k)):
  if(len(k)==2):
    s.append(0)
  else:
    s.append(1)
```

This is giving some unknown error.Overall what required is the new column should have 1 if k has some value else 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**
[piRSquared's improvement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46863437/how-to-update-new-column-based-on-exsisting-column-in-python/46863473?noredirect=1#comment80674557_46863473) involves exploiting the falseyness of sets.

```
df['Fatal'] = df['Dead_notdead'].astype(bool).astype(int)
```

This works because `{}` translates to `False`!

---

**Option 2**
You can call `str.len` and convert the resultant boolean mask to an integer type using `astype`.

```
df['Fatal'] = df['Dead_notdead'].str.len().gt(0).astype(int)
```

---

If you have a column of *strings* (not `set` objects), convert it first, using `ast`:

```
import ast
df['Dead_notdead'] = df['Dead_notdead'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
```

Comment: @JonClements Oops, major typo there.

Comment: Don't you want a `.map(bool).astype(int)` somewhere there?

Comment: @JonClements `.gt(0)` = ( `> 0`)  generates a boolean mask, which is then converted to a column of `0s/1s` using jstype.

Comment: Ah... was reading the bottom bit as standalone... didn't click it was just demo'ing getting it into a set where you then apply the lines above... ignore me :)

Comment: astype(bool).astype(int)

Comment: @piRSquared Does `gt(0)` not already result in a bool mask? Also, welcome back :)

Comment: Only because you’re applying len. Empty sets are falsey

Comment: @piRSquared Oh, I see what you mean. Just the astype(bool).astype(int) is enough! Wow, did not think of that.

Answer (score 0):

you could put that logic in a list comprehension. It creates a list that can be passed into the new column like a series.

`df['Fatal'] = [1 if len(item) > 0 else 0 for item in df.Dead_notdead]`